# How can I return a list of results as JSON?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to return the result of a query as JSON.  I'm using the following route to return one model instance as a JSON object.

```
@mod.route('/autocomplete/<term>', methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete(term):

    country = Country.query.filter(Country.name_pt.ilike('%'+ term + '%')).first()

    country_dict = country.__dict__
    country_dict.pop('_sa_instance_state', None)

    return jsonify(json_list=country_dict)
```

This code works well  if I use the `first()` method.  However, I need to use the `all()` to get all results.  When I do that, I get the following error.

```
country_dict = country.__dict__
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

What should I be doing to return the entire list of results as JSON?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do that "jsonify preparation step" for each item in the list, since `.all()` returns a list of model instances, not just one instance like `.first()`.  Work on a copy of each `__dict__` so you don't mess with SQLAlchemy's internal representation of the instances.

```
@mod.route('/autocomplete/<term>', methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete(term):
    countries = []

    for country in Country.query.filter(Country.name_pt.ilike('%' + term + '%'):
        country_dict = country.__dict__.copy()
        country_dict.pop('_sa_instance_state', None)
        countries.append(country_dict)

    return jsonify(json_list=countries)
```

Probably better just to return the data about each country explicitly, rather than trying to magically jsonify the instance.

```
@mod.route('/autocomplete/<term>', methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete(term):
    countries = []

    for country in Country.query.filter(Country.name_pt.ilike('%' + term + '%'):
        countries.append({
            'id': country.id,
            'name': country.name_pt,
        })

    return jsonify(countries=countries)
```